# Getting information from Keycloak Token in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, keycloak

I have Key cloak token which is generated after getting logged in UI.
I passed this token to backend which is  nodeJS.
In node I want to get information for this user like user role,user id.
Is there any module or pakage for this?

Answer (score 3):

```
npm install -save jsonwebtoken
```

```
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
obj = jwt.decode(token);
```

The obj contains any information like role, userid, ...